# Forecasting error from GLS estimator

Tags: forecasting, generalized-least-squares

As well known, $\text{Var}(\beta_{gls})\leqslant \text{Var}(\beta_{ols})$.

From this, we can conjecture that the following inequality also holds: 
$$\text{E}(y_{T+1}-X_{T}\beta_{gls}|\iota(T))^2 \leqslant \text{E}(y_{T+1}-X_{T}\beta_{ols}|\iota(T))^2,$$

where $\iota(T)$ is all information up tp time $T$.

I am trying to verify this mathematically, but it is quite hard.

Does anyone have a nice idea of how to do this?

Comment: Are you sure the time subscript for $y$ is different from the time subscript for $X$? I don't think the second inequality holds as it is.

Comment: Sure, it should be the forecasting error for $T+1$

Comment: Then you should make it clear that $y_{T+1}$ is to be matched with $X_T$. You could for example state what model is used to relate $y$ to $X$ (e.g. $y_t=X_{t-1} \beta+\varepsilon_t$).

Comment: Yes, the model you just referred can be one of them.

Comment: Including this information in the post (rather than only in the comments) could make it clearer.

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem? It would be interesting to see the solution.

Comment: Not yet, actually this is a crucial point in my dissertation If I do that I will let you know